# Does simple membership supports password format and password retrieval?

Tags: simplemembership

I am using a simple membership Provider and I want to retrieve a password to resend the login credentials to a user.

For this I have set `enablePasswordRetrieval=true` also `requireQuestionAndAnswer=false`. However, it gives an error on `Getpassword()`, says method is not supported.

Comment: .NET? Something else? Please consider adding a few more tags to help work out what your question is about.

Answer (score 2):

SimpleMembership does not directly support retrieving the password.  Instead it provides a method for getting a token to send to the user so they can reset their password. Here is an [article that describes how to add password reset to your application](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/04/password-reset-with-simplemembership.html).

The password is stored in the database encrypted using a one-way hash algorithm so there is no way to decrypt it and present it to the user.